# instataneous frequency in FM

Tags: frequency-modulation

Newbie and trying to understand the concept of instantaneous frequency in FM.

Basic equation is \$A\cos(2\pi f_\mathrm{c}t+ 2\pi k\int (\mathrm{message})\,\mathrm{d}t)\$. I wanted to know how the term   \$2\pi k\int (\mathrm{message})\,\mathrm{d}t\$ term creates chirpiness in the carrier frequency

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with "chirpiness". Also, have you looked at how *frequency* is defined, based on *phase* (hint: derivatives)? And what's the *phase* of your signal here?

Comment: assuming phase is zero. The above equation (integral term) creates the frequency deviation from the carrier frequency. Wanted to understand how the integral of message would create the instantaneous frequency to change?

Comment: again, **definition** of frequency. Apply it!